# How to detect discoloration on an image using OpenCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, .net-core, detection

I have a algorithmic problem: I have to detect discoloration on image. I have a scan of a photo (I don't know what is on the photo), and I want to get information about it may appear a discoloration.

Maybe anyone know how to do it using OpenCV (I'm using opencvsharp3 wrapper)?

Comment: Can you upload some examples of the scanned photos? Its difficult for us to help without seeing the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "discoloraton"? Perhaps if you can define it clearly enough, you'll see how to find it programmatically.

Comment: I have something like this: [link](http://www.morethantechnical.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-14-at-2.11.04-AM-e1421302841194.png) 
There is a bad image on left side and good image on right side. I want to make alghoritm who can help me with detecting bad colors like on the image on left. But I think that can be very difficult without using something like machine learning etc., I'm right?